# Flutter. The class 'StreamSink' can't be extended outside of its library because it's an interface class

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

Intento echar a andar el proyecto [flutter_bluetooth_serial 0.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) y me da una cantidad muy grande de errores, sobre todo con las versiones, así que intento montarlo poco a poco, empezando por la [api](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/tree/master/lib) que implementa para Bluetooth.

Pues bien, en el archivo [BluetoothConnection.dart](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/blob/master/lib/BluetoothConnection.dart), línea 94, me aparece un error que no sé cómo resolver. Me dice que una clase que se usa no la puedo extender fuera de su librería por ser interface.

¿Qué hago entonces con esa clase, cómo la implemento, alguna sugerencia?

¿Por qué esto funcionaba en una versión anterior de flutter y ahora no? Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]